# Applying a proposal called "Code Golf" is ok on area51? or should it be under Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal, code-golf

I've created a proposal on area51 called ["Code Golf"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf), but after that I rethink that current Code Golf questions on Stack Overflow looks no problem as long as it is Community Wiki. So I am confused about to continue or to delete.

What is your opinion on it? Code Golf questions should be on Stack Overflow as is?

Comment: Have you thought about making it a more generic site than only allowing Code Golf questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no widespread consensus on whether code golf should be allowed on SO (should be plenty of history of that on Meta somewhere), but, rather than argue, it's tolerated under certain rules and at lower frequencies.  (I still downvote them all once a month or so, but they're CW anyway.)

Leave the proposal.  Maybe it can gain momentum and everyone can be happier.

Comment: Note I downvote the questions, not the answers; I'm only semi-retired, but not enough time for the latter.